# Error when trying to launch powershell script from WinForms App

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powershell

So I've been following the guide made online that demonstrates how to run a powershell script from a windows form app using VB.Net. However I keep running into this problem that I cannot for the life of me find the answer to or anything close to lead me to an answer.

```
    Dim myRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace
    myRunSpace.Open()
    Dim mypipeline As Pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
    Dim command As String = " .'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; get-mailbox -recipienttypedetails UserMailbox | select-object DisplayName,RecipientTypeDetails,PrimarySmtpAddress"
    mypipeline.Commands.AddScript(command)
    mypipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
    Dim outputs As Collection(Of PSObject) = mypipeline.Invoke()
    'myRunSpace.Close()
    Dim MyStringBuiler As New StringBuilder()
    For Each result As PSObject In outputs
        MyStringBuiler.AppendLine(result.ToString())
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(MyStringBuiler.ToString)
    '        ReadExchangeCSVFile()
```

That is my code and it follows closely what the example does. However, I keep getting this error :

```
{"Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics  because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified."}Source : System.Management.Automation
```

From research I've gathered so far it may be mismatching versions of libraries I'm importing and the powershell version installed on the machine.

The line that errors out is the first one in the code snippet above. So when creating the runspace it shows me the error when debugging.

Comment: It may definitely be incompatible versions, you can find out if you create an empty project and then load powershell. If it works then, you have references that do not fit together in COM components. Like exchange cmdlets that use the same AD com object but in a different version.

Comment: @Christoph so I create an empty windows form project and try and load a powershell from there ? or what exactly do yolu mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. If it works in an empty windows form project without a lot of references that means you have a conflict (and then happy interprocess communication!).

If it does not work neither, it means you are lucky and just have to find which DLL is missing (you can have a look with fusion log viewer or show a message box in the according event handler):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module StartUp

    Public Sub Main(args As String())
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CustomResolver
        'Load powershell here

    End Sub

    Private Function CustomResolver(sender As Object, args As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly
        MsgBox($"Assembly {args.Name} not found!{vbCrLf}{vbCrLf}(referred by {args.RequestingAssembly?.Modules?.FirstOrDefault()?.FullyQualifiedName})")
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Just ran this and It gave me a different error :{"An error occurred while attempting to load the system Windows PowerShell snap-ins. Please contact Microsoft Customer Support Services."} -- so my problem is missing dlls? and i need to find which are missing.

Comment: so i know which ones I need , just not how to install/add them to the project or computer

Comment: It's a long time ago I had these problems, and I tried to push it aside. I run the main application, the exchange-related powershell commands, the active directory related ones and the file server related ones in 4 different processes on 3 different machines in the end. Exchange cmdlets interfer with Active Directory ones (we used the ones from Quest, now Dell). Exchange uses remote cmdlets which are trouble, and they like to run only on x64. I had to load them manually, and some of the assemblies are mixed native/CLI (IJW) which have to be loaded through the right overload (only 1 works)...

Comment: When I find time I look it up how I did it then, but I don't have the code stored on this machine (and it is about 10 years old). Not sure whether a DLL is missing or what the problem is, try to execute each command that is stored in your RemoteExchange.ps1 as an own command and see where the error occurs.

Comment: From further research I've gathered it seems the two assemblies not found were System.Management.Automation.resources as well as Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics. I am trying to run it on Windows 2012 AD R2 with Powershell 1.0 installed on it, some people tell me the problem is those assemblies are not installed in this version , I cannot change to powershell 3.0 which introduced Runspaces. Thank you for the continued support it means alot.

Comment: Powershell 1.0 is probably only the name of the folder, that would be an ancient version that surely would not support current Exchange cmdlets. See $PSVersionTable. I don't understand your statement "I cannot Change to powershell 3.0 which introduced Runspaces.". You are clearly depending on the runspace in your code above.

Comment: Yeah the problem was that my code was using runspaces which are used in powershell version 3.0 and above. I had 1.0 installed, so I upgraded to 3.0 and the code now runs.